# $x=p_1p_2p_3$ ans $p_1+p_2+p_3 = p_4 ^ {p_5}$ and $5 \leq p_1, p_2, p_3,p_4,p_5 \leq 50$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

> $x=p_1p_2p_3$ ans $p_1+p_2+p_3 = p_4 ^ {p_5}$. If $5 \leq p_1, p_2, p_3,p_4,p_5 \leq 50$ and all of them are distinct primes then find the minimum value of $x$.

I tried with just plugging in primes and check if that works. But I don't think this will lead me to the minimum solution. How to systemically solve this?
**Source**: BdMO 2016 Chittagong Regional Secondary problem 8.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but we have $p_4^{p_5}\ge 5^5=3125$ and $p_1+p_2+p_3<150$.

Comment: Does all primes need to be distinct? Also this question seems wrong since last three primes close to $50$ sum up to $131 < 5^5$

Comment: @Xam The question is not saying $p_1<p_2<p_3<p_4<p_5$ .They just need to be distinct.